# Is it possible to use Protractor as a library in a Selenium Webdriver project using eclipse

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am a newbie to testing angular JS applications, I have managed to run my first protractor test.
However as I have already developed an End to End test suite with selenium Java webdriver and I would like to use selenium's Javascript webdriver the same way.

What I want to do is add required selenium and protractor library to my build path and then starting using both Java and JS webdriver?

Is this technically possible before starting exploring the idea?

Thanks
Zied

Answer (score 0):

Given that the protractor tests are testing high-level how your application behaves in the browser you are in a word killing 2 birds with one stone - you're testing both the angular functionality of your client side interactivity and the results being shown on the page from the java backend. I would recommend porting the java tests into protractorjs.